# Is it possible to restrict all MVC actions to HttpPost only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am asked to apply `[HttpPost]` to all the actions of one MVC project for security reason says POST is more secure than GET, which I disagree with.

But anyway, is it possible to do so?

If it is, what about those `<a href='Somewhere'>Click Me</a>` and scripts like `window.location='http:\\xxx.xxx\Somewhere'`? They all sent GET request right?

#### Update

Just informed that it's a high-priority issue of Fortify report - ''ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST".

Comment: And how would you ever navigate to anything

Comment: what security reasons? How would you navigate to a view? If you have any sensitive information or restricting any info to specific users, you can handle that in your action methods. Unless you are actually posting something, there is no need to add this.

Comment: the only security reason I can think of is that GET requests end up in server logs as full URL plus data, while POST requests end up in logs only as URL. Switching to POST will by no means stop a hacker, it will only keep logs a bit cleaner, which means in an eventual breach, the logs wont give away too much information. Same goes for any proxy in between (which is a slightly bigger concern, logs are under your control, proxy might not be).

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu `GET` is for getting stuff from the server, `POST` is for posting stuff to the server, as simple as that.

Comment: @trashr0x it hasnt been that simple for a while now, welcome to 21st century :)

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu if it's not simple you're not doing it right.

Comment: GET methods used to get resource from server, POST methods used to send submitted values to be processed in server. Of course you can't simply set all action methods to accept only POST request, also you will meet dead-end when redirecting in all-POST methods since redirect requires GET method to target page (remember PRG pattern).

Comment: I dont think we are talking about ALL requests here, are we ? I believe we are talking about webservices. Not regular site navigation, right ?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC first call you make will/should be of type HttpGet , In MVC default i.e if you don't mention the Action will be of type HttpGet .

In your case if you want your HttGet to be secure you can use many methodoligies like [Authorize] attribute [RequireHttps] , encode html etc .

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {
   return View();
 }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Employee model)
 {

       //some logic

  return View(model);
 }
```